# Converting a 9 digit number into three 3 digit number

Tags: c, math, logic

Ok everyone so i have a 9 digit number in input (`123456789`) and i need to break it down to first middle and last three numbers (`123,456,789`).
 I know that i can use modulo to get the last three digits.

```
first_group_of_three = input number % 1000;
```

But i have no idea how to get the other two groups.
Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE !
Thanks to milevyo answer i managed to figure it out.Now for the code freaks out there,i am a beginner programmer and i would like to ask what is a more efficient way to write this code(below),maybe using less variables or some other technique.I didn't transform it to char because we are not allowed to since we still "havent learned it"

```
     scanf("%d" , &input_number);
   last_group_of_three = input_number % 1000;
   temp = (input_number-last_group_of_three)/1000;
   middle_group_of_three = temp % 1000;
   first_group_of_three = (temp-middle_group_of_three)/1000;
```

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: Divide by 1000 and use modulo.

Comment: umm... divide.  This is a 4th grade math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I know its a math problem,thats why i tagged math,i'm very bad at even basic math because i missed out on it when i learned it in school,so my apologies if this annoys someone

Comment: @LuanL This is a Q & A site.  Rather than change the question, accept an answer (you can even post your own answer) if an acceptable one if found and _then_ post your new question with a link back to this one (and emphasize the need for the new post).

Answer (score 1):

```
first_group_of_three = input number % 1000;
shift=(input number-first_group_of_three)/1000

second_group_of_three = shift % 1000;

and so on
```

Comment: Why not just `shift= input number/1000;`?

Comment: if some one want to use float instead of int, what would be the result?

Comment: If one wanted to use `float`, `input number % 1000` would not have compiled - so the result of `input number/1000` is irrelevant .  `fmodf()` would be used instead of `%`.  So it is certain OP's code was using integers.

Comment: it has no sence, but i keep the logic.

Comment: `first_group_of_three` is not the first group (assuming LTR layout). Keeping useless code even after you were informed about this fact is unusual. It's almost like you are striving to write sub-par quality answers even if you could write better ones. At least that's how I read your profile.

Comment: in theory things works as i said, in practice things works as @chux said, thank you again chux

Answer (score 1):

Simplification:  [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154241/converting-a-9-digit-number-into-three-3-digit-number/33157281#comment54117819_33154241)

```
scanf("%d", &input_number);

last_group_of_three = input_number % 1000;
input_number /= 1000;

middle_group_of_three = input_number % 1000;
input_number /= 1000;

// % 1000 only if original input exceeded 9 digits
first_group_of_three = input_number % 1000;
```

Note: many compilers will optimize the `% 1000` and `/ 1000` into a single operation providing the two results: remainder & quotient.

(OP has not mention what code should do with negative numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can input the numbers as string in a char table and then the first 3 numbers will stay the 4th char of table will be the char ',' and the 5th,6th,7th char will be the next 3 numbers etc. So you will finally create the string "123,456,789", then print.